# Column color using the `colortbl` package - Example 4 in the manual

Tags: tables, colortbl

I'm trying to regenerate the colorful example on page 2-3 in the manual for the  [`colortbl` package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/colortbl?lang=en), see screen shoot below. (Note that the table spans over two pages).

[image]

In the manual it is written:

> This example shows rather poor taste but is quite colourful! Inspect the source file, [colortbl.dtx](http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex2e/contrib/colortbl/colortbl.dtx), to see the full code for the example, but it uses the following column types.

In the code below I have extracted (from [colortbl.dtx](http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex2e/contrib/colortbl/colortbl.dtx))  the code section that I think is relevant. However, the code won't compile. I'm left with a long list of errors. Can anyone identify were the (code) error is?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{longtable}

% Before starting give a little space: 
\setlength\minrowclearance{2pt}

% This example shows rather poor taste but is quite colourful! Inspect the source
% file, colortbl.dtx, to see the full code for the example, but it uses the following
% column types. 

\newcolumntype{A}{%
    >{\color{white}\columncolor{red}[.5\tabcolsep]%
        \raggedright}%
    p{2cm}}

\newcolumntype{B}{%
    >{\columncolor{blue}[.5\tabcolsep]%
        \color{yellow}\raggedright}
    p{3cm}}

\newcolumntype{C}{%
    >{\columncolor{yellow}[.5\tabcolsep]}%
    D{.}{\cdot}{3.3}}

\newcolumntype{E}{%
    >{\large\bfseries
        \columncolor{cyan}[.5\tabcolsep]}c}

\newcolumntype{F}{%
    >{\color{white}
        \columncolor{magenta}[.5\tabcolsep]}c}

\newcolumntype{G}{%
    >{\columncolor[gray]{0.8}[.5\tabcolsep][\tabcolsep]}l}

\newcolumntype{H}{>{\columncolor[gray]{0.8}}l}

\newcolumntype{I}{%
    >{\columncolor[gray]{0.8}[\tabcolsep][.5\tabcolsep]}%
    D{.}{\cdot}{3.3}}


\begin{document}

% The code below is directly extracted from colortbl.dtx
% http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex2e/contrib/colortbl/colortbl.dtx

\begin{longtable}{ABC}
    \multicolumn{3}{E}{A long table example}\\
    \multicolumn{2}{F}{First two columns}&
    \multicolumn{1}{F}{Third column}\\
    \multicolumn{2}{F}{p-type}&
    \multicolumn{1}{F}{D-type (\textsf{dcolumn})}\endfirsthead
    \multicolumn{3}{E}{A long table example (continued)}\\
    \multicolumn{2}{F}{First two columns}&
    \multicolumn{1}{F}{Third column}\\
    \multicolumn{2}{F}{p-type}&
    \multicolumn{1}{F}{D-type (\textsf{dcolumn})}\endhead
    \multicolumn{3}{E}{Continued\ldots}\endfoot
    \multicolumn{3}{E}{The End}\endlastfoot
    P-column&and another one&12.34\\
    \multicolumn{1}{G}{Total}&
    \multicolumn{1}{H}{(wrong)}&
    \multicolumn{1}{I}{100.6}\\
    Some long text in the first column&bbb&1.2\\
    aaa&and some long text in the second column&1.345\\
    \multicolumn{1}{G}{Total}&
    \multicolumn{1}{H}{(wrong)}&
    \multicolumn{1}{I}{100.6}\\
    aaa&bbb&1.345\\
    Note that the coloured rules in all columns stretch to accomodate
    arge entries in one column. &bbb&1.345\\
    aaa&bbb&100\\
    aaa&Depending on your driver you may get unsightly gaps or lines
    where the  `screens' used to produce different shapes interact
    badly. You may want to cause adjacent panels of the same colour by
    specifying a larger overhang 
    or by adding some negative space (in a "\noalign" between rows.&12.4\\
    aaa&bbb&45.3\\
\end{longtable}


\end{document}
```

*Note, this is a [continuation of a previous post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/334903/column-color-using-the-colortbl-package/334908#334908) that discussed the first three Tables in the manual.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the `dcolumn` package for the D column and `\verb"\noalign"` for the verbatim on the last line of text.

Straight from the egreg school of typographic good taste:

[image]

Comment: This should be downvoted 100 times. It is ***your*** table!